# Using a queuing system to do custom logic

Tags: .net, notifications, queue, message-queue

I am developing a notification engine, this notification engine will send several types of notifications to several receivers.

1. Email Notification
2. Push Notification
3. ...

When a certain client communicates with the notification engine in order to send a notification, the engine must store this notification in a certain queue, before communicating with the receiver.

I have a requirement that the flow should be as the below:

1. Then notification engine must check if the receiver is able to send notifications now.
2. If the receiver can send notifications, the message will be sent to it
3. If the receiver cannot send notifications, the message must stay in the queue, and then try to be processed later.

**For example, if I am sending an email notification, the Email receiver is running but the SMTP server is not accessible, so the receiver will not be able to send the email notification. The notification should stay in the queue, and will be processed later.**

I know that there are several queuing systems that I may use like **MSMQ** and **RabbitMQ**.

What are the best practices that I can use in order to develop my logic and fulfill the requirements?

Comment: Why do the notification engine cannot send the message to the email receiver if the smtp server is not accessible? The email receiver can have a queue to and it will unqueue message only if the smtp server is accessible

Comment: I am trying to unify the logic of the queuing in the notification engine, I do not want each receiver to implement it is own queuing system.

Comment: If I put the logic of queuing in the email receiver, how can I do the logic to sent the email when the SMTP will be ready.

Comment: The email receiver/email service (the service in charge of sending email to the smtp server) will dequeue message from its queue only if the smtp server is accessible. The email receiver has the responsability to know if the smtp is accessible but not the notification engine.

Comment: The notification engine sends the notification request message into the queue of the service/receiver in charge of the notification. Each service has a dedicated queue. Services will dequeue messages only if they can technically process the request. So notification engine and services are loosely coupled